# Kann man 'ein hätte' sagen?

Tags: vocabulary

I responded to a prompt on Italki about a car free day and wrote:

*Einerseits haette ein internationaler autofreier Tag ein goesser Wirkung an die Niveau von Karbon dioxid in Atmosphaere*

It was then corrected to:

*Ein hätte ein internationaler autofreier Tag eine grosse Wirkung auf die Niveau des CO2s in der Atmosphare*

Obviously I understand the rest of the corrections made but I dont understand why the sentance can start with 'Ein hätte'

Comment: I don't understand that correction either. How does the text go on? Is there an "andererseits"?

Comment: "Niveau" erscheint mir auch keine gute Wahl zu sein. Vielleicht "Anteil".

Comment: Oder Gehalt ? Wenn weniger Gehalt mehr ist :-)

Comment: Erst mal ist das für mich sachlich ungenau. Bestenfalls wirkt sich so ein Tag auf den Anstieg der CO2-Konzentration aus, nämlich verlangsamend, nicht aber auf die Konzentration als solche, die steigt weiter, nur ein zwei Tage etwas langsamer. Zu den anderen Fehlern wurde hier schon viel gesagt.

Answer (score 6):

> Einerseits hätte

is correct. *Ein hätte* doesn't make sense.

There is another mistake in the corrected version. It's **das** Niveau, not *die*.

> Einerseits hätte ein internationaler autofreier Tag eine große Wirkung auf das Niveau des CO2 in der Atmosphäre ...

Answer (score 4):

Neither the original nor the allegedly corrected version is correct. In fact, the latter is even worse, especially, as *ein hätte* doesn't make any sense.

> Einerseits <s>haette</s> hätte ein internationaler autofreier Tag <s>ein goesser</s> eine große Wirkung <s>an die</s> auf das Niveau von <s>Karbon dioxid in Atmosphaere</s> Kohlendioxid in der Atmosphäre, …

As users @CarstenS and @a_donda suggest in their comments below the question, you could additionally replace *auf das Niveau* by *auf den Anteil* or *auf den Gehalt* for stylistic reasons.

Comment: Was ist an "Niveau" auszusetzen?

Comment: @userunknown, frag Carsten. Ich finde *Niveau* auch okay, sehe aber auch, dass *Anteil* oder *Gehalt* noch treffender sind.

Comment: @ user unknown - In Deutschland ist es glaube ich üblich, einfach von der CO2-Konzentration oder wie von @Kritiker der Elche weiter unten genannt vom CO2-Anteil (in der Atmosphäre) zu sprechen, aber es gibt auch Belege mit 'Niveau der CO2-Konzentration'. Für mich ist letzteres ansatzweise pleonastisch, wie _die Höhe des Preises ist unter 10 Euro_.

Answer (score 1):

That both variants are incorrect has already been explained in the other answers. Here some more remarks concerning the mistakes (mistakes in italics, corrections in brackets):

- Einerseits *haette* [hätte] ein internationaler autofreier Tag *ein goesser Wirkung* [eine große Wirkung] *an die Niveau* [auf das Niveau] von *Karbon dioxid* [Kohlendioxid / CO2] *in Atmosphaere* [in der Atmosphäre].
- *Ein* [does not make any sense here!] hätte ein internationaler autofreier Tag eine *grosse* [große] Wirkung auf *die* [das] Niveau des CO2s in der *Atmosphare* [Atmosphäre].

Thus a grammatically correct version is

> Einerseits hätte ein internationaler autofreier Tag eine große Wirkung auf das Niveau von Kohlendioxid (CO2) in der Atmosphäre.

However, it still sounds a bit cumbersome. Why is that?

1. If you begin a sentence with "einerseits", then everybody expects a second part beginning with "andererseits". Perhaps you omitted that part in your question?
2. Although "auf das Niveau von Kohlendioxid"  is linguistically correct, one should better write "auf den CO2-Anteil" or "auf den CO2-Gehalt".

Comment: Of course the *andererseits* is missing here. but it has nothing to do with the question. Why would a chemical formula be better than the name *Kohlendioxid*? Or is it about *Anteil* or *Gehalt* instead of *Niveau*? I don't agree with *one should better* ...

Comment: @Olafant Of course Kohlendioxid is correct, but it is not frequently used in news articles. For example, *CO2-Emissionen* occurs much more often than *Kohlendioxid-Emissionen*.  A Google search gives 17.300.000  hits vs. 1.180.000 hits. So why arguing against CO2?

Comment: @Olafant Would you really use the phrase "Kohlendioxid-Niveau der Atmosphäre"? Look at [this text](https://www.rbb24.de/panorama/thema/2020/coronavirus/beitraege_neu/2020/10/co2-emissionen-rueckgang-corona-pik-potsdam-.html): "Während des monatelangen Lockdowns im Frühjahr 2020 sind die CO2-Emissionen weltweit um fast neun Prozent zurückgegangen. Das berichten Potsdamer Klimaforscher, die an einer internationalen Studie mitwirkten. Einen längerfristigen Rückgang sehen sie aber nicht. [...] Die Autoren weisen darauf hin,

Comment: dass die meisten Volkswirtschaften nach dem Ende starker Corona-Beschränkungen wieder ihr gewohntes **Kohlendioxid-Niveau** erreicht hätten - bis auf einen anhaltenden Rückgang des CO2-Ausstoßes beim Verkehr. Langfristig würde sich der coronabedingte CO2-Rückgang aber nur geringfügig auf die CO2-Konzentration in der Atmosphäre auswirken: Dort habe sich bereits so viel CO2 angesammelt, dass es Jahrtausende überdauern werde." Here the expression *Kohlendioxid-Niveau* does not refer to the atmosphere, but to economies.

Comment: @KritikerderElche The original phrase is *"... auf das Niveau von [CO2 / Kohlendioxid] in der Atmosphäre ..."*. CO2 is just Kohlendioxid.

Comment: @Olafant Of course CO2 is the molecular formula for Kohlendioxid, so can can use both alternatively. What I wanted to ask you is whether you would really say "Niveau von CO2 / Kohlendioxid in der Atmosphäre"  -  or would you use something like "CO2-Anteil/Gehalt/Konzentration der Atmosphäre"? The purpose of the above quotation was to support my personal impression that "CO2-Niveau" in the sense of *concentration* is highly unusual.

Answer (score 1):

Zu der Frage, warum ***"Ein hätte ..."*** nicht geht:

Das *hätte* ist der finite (konjugierte) Teil des Prädikats in diesem Satz. Dieser Teil steht in einem deutschen Aussagesatz immer auf Position 2, das ist hier erfüllt. Auf Position 1 kann nahezu jeder andere Satzteil stehen, oft das Subjekt (***ich** hätte um 14 Uhr Zeit*), nicht selten ein Objekt (***das** hätte ich nicht von dir gedacht*), recht oft auch eine Adverbialbestimmung (***an deiner Stelle** hätte ich noch einen Tag mit der Antwort gewartet*).

Mit *Position 1* ist nicht *Wort mit der Nummer 1* gemeint, sondern ein Platz für die Aufnahme (Einsetzung) einer funktionellen Gruppe. Die gesamte Gruppe ***ein internationaler autofreier Tag*** könnte zum Beispiel die **Funktionsgruppe *Subjekt*** sein, danach käme das finite Verb *hätte*, wie gesagt auf Position 2.

Ein Subjekt kann aus **einem** Wort bestehen, zum Beispiel einem Namen wie *London* oder *Peter*, oder aus einem Pronomen wie *du* oder *der* (***der** hätte das anders entschieden* - umgangssprachlich für *er hätte das anders entschieden*). **Ein** kann immer nur ein unbestimmter Artikel sein, das dazugehörige Pronomen wäre *einer* (***Einer** (allein) hätte nicht viel bewirkt von diesen autofreien Tagen* - umgangssprachlich salopp für *Ein solcher autofreier Tag hätte nicht viel bewirkt*.) *Ein* ohne nachfolgendes Substantiv ist eine unvollständige Funktionsgruppe, vergleiche *A would have a significant impact...*

Meine normalisierte Version der vermutlich gewünschten Aussageabsicht wäre:

> Ein internationaler autofreier Tag würde sich erheblich / merklich auf die (Zunahme der) CO2-Konzentration in der Atmosphäre auswirken.

Comment: "CO2-Konzentration" halte ich für den bisher besten Vorschlag.